# write a bash function that mimic 'return' builtin

Tags: bash, exception, return, return-value, continuations

I'm trying to write a bash function that would do the equivalent of the `return` builtin, it could be used like this:

```sh
f() {
    echo a
    my_return 15
    echo c 
    return 17
}
```

It would have to behave exactly as `return` builtin is expected to work.

The context is that I'm looking in the depth of `bash` for fun/experiments to mainly see if we can implement some higher language constructs and notions as are exceptions, continuations or similar concepts in `bash`.

I actually managed to implement the breaking of the instruction flow by using `DEBUG` trap returning a value of 2 (as explained in `extdebug` part of the bash manual, this simulates a `return` in the current function, but doesn't set the return value of it), the only problem is that this return value of 2 is then passed as the return value of the whole function, thus removing me the possibility to set it to an arbitrary value.

Using `RETURN` trap did not seem to work neither. It seems we can't set the return value of the function in any way. I achieved already pretty impressive flow control feats thanks to `DEBUG`/`RETURN` traps, and the goal seems not so far anymore.

So would you know about a way to achieve this implementation of `my_return` in pure bash, with current implementation ? if not, what minimal modification would you suggest in bash implementation to allow this ? (I'm thinking of patches maybe on `trap.c` on `run_{debug,return}_trap` functions, allowing to set the return value of the returning function, or maybe adding a custom bash `builtin`, as it seems to be quite pluggable here).